# List ports which do not have a given property

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

What would be the easiest was to accomplish this?

Find all ports that do not have 'switchport port-security'

```
show run | exclude ?
```

I don't have a swicth with me and packet tracer does not have the commands avaliable.

Comment: Are you fluent in `vi`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you're willing to use a python script, use [ciscoconfparse.find_parents_wo_child()](http://pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_CiscoConfParse.html).

In your case, usage would be:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse('/path/to/configuration/file')
missing = parse.find_parents_wo_child('^interface', 'switchport port-security$')
for intf in missing:
    print(intf)
```

Save that script to a file and run it (after you install ciscoconfparse).  That script will print interfaces without port-security.

This is the github link to the library: [ciscoconfparse](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse)

Full disclosure: I am the author of the library

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to make exclude work in this situation.

You could try something like the below which will show all the interfaces port-security lines (you would just need to find interfaces with none of those - i.e. where you have two interface lines in a row):

```
 show run | include (^interface|port-security)
```

Or, if this is the specific case you are trying to achieve, a simple `show port-security` will list all the ports that have port-security enabled.

Comment: Starting with your `include` command, you might put the result in a file. From there with `vi` write a macro which will join any line prior one containing `port-security`. Finally remove all the lines containing `port-security`. The remaining lines are the ports without `port-security`.